# Disable trimming in Button text

Tags: android, trim, android-button

I would like to display white spaces before and after text on a Button. For example :

```java
 "    A    "
```

However when I set the text above to a Button :

```
myButton.setText ( "    A    " );
```

The text is trimmed (only trailing spaces are removed), and the following text is displayed :

```
"    A"
```

How can I display the text without having it trimmed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

For example

Use `btn.setText(Html.fromHtml("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;"));`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply !

Answer (score 0):

Use XML encoding `&#160;` or `\u0020` for whitespaces.

```
<string name="your_id">&#160; String &#160; </string>

<string name="your_id">\u0020 String \u0020</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trailing spaces are treated that way naturally apart from some legacy systems.

If the reason is only to have the button width set to a certain size, why not use the following in you XML layout:

```
android:layout_width="130dp" // Set the width according to needs in pixels
```

or like following in your code:

```
mybuttonn.setWidth(50); // Set the width according to needs in pixels
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for.